# Returning incorrect values of floor function in C++

Tags: c++, floor

The code:

```
    cout << log(25.0/9.0)/log(5.0/3.0) << endl << floor(log(25.0/9.0)/log(5.0/3.0));
```

results:

```
2
1
```

Why does C++ considers floor(2) = 1?

**What I tried:**
When saving the fraction in a float it returns the correct value:

```
float a = log(25.0/9.0)/log(5.0/3.0);
cout << a << endl << floor(a);
```

results:

```
2
2
```

Comment: What happens if you display the first number at maximum precision? I suspect it's being rounded up during printing. The narrowing conversion from `double` to `float` may round up as well.

Comment: It's a rounding error. Your calculation results in a value of 1.999999999999999999 (approxmately) which is rounded up when printing (correctly) and rounded down by `floor` (again correctly).

Comment: It's also being rounded up when converting from `double` to `float`. Try this code `double a = log(25.0/9.0)/log(5.0/3.0); cout << a << endl << floor(a);`

Comment: The whole problem is of precision of float and respective conversion while printing. You can check by using line `cout << log(25.0/9.0)<<endl<<log(5.0/3.0) << endl;`  where you found **log(25.0/9.0) = 1.02165** and **log(5.0/3.0) = 0.510826** with an difference of 0.510826 * 2 - 1.02165 = 0.000002 which is causing the error.

Comment: When working with floating point numbers you should not expect mathematical correctness. The results you've got are the correct results in terms of floating point arithmetic. You might not be happy about that but its the limitations of working with floating point arithmetic. [Further reading](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @john What difference does saving the result in a variable make? I mean why does it solve the issue?

Answer (score 4):

Set your precision. floor is correct;

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(20) << std::endl << log(25.0 / 9.0) / log(5.0 / 3.0) << std::endl << floor(log(25.0 / 9.0) / log(5.0 / 3.0)) << std::endl;

float a = log(25.0 / 9.0) / log(5.0 / 3.0);
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(20) << std::endl<< a << std::endl << floor(a) << std::endl;

double b = log(25.0 / 9.0) / log(5.0 / 3.0);
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(20) << std::endl << b << std::endl << floor(b) << std::endl;
```

this produces

1.99999999999999955591
1.00000000000000000000

2.00000000000000000000
2.00000000000000000000

1.99999999999999955591
1.00000000000000000000

Comment: I understand now that it's a precision problem. Any tips on how to deal with this issue to get the correct answer?

Comment: And can you please explain why did it work when I saved the result in a variable?

Comment: The reason is your variable a is a float which has less precision than a double.

Comment: I updated the answer to show you

Answer (score 1):

I complied and checked the whole code and let me share my analysis with you.

If you do log(25.0/9.0)/log(5.0/3.0)  division directly the compiler treats it as double and the double division result is equal to 1.9999999999999996. If it is rounded it will become 2 and if floor operation is done on this it will become 1 as  floor() function in C++ returns the largest possible integer value which is less than or equal to the given argument. In this example it will always return 1.

If the division log(25.0/9.0)/log(5.0/3.0) is treated as float it will result in 2.0000000039152304 (treating each operand as float and storing result in double for understanding) hence in this case round and floor operation will have same result that is 2.

Good Luck

Comment: But shouldn't `double` give you more precision? And what can I do to get the correct answer?

Comment: Yes double gives you more precision thats why it is more accurate result.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem two days ago when I was solving a problem on Codeforces. I was using floor function and its returning its different value. I went to google and found some answers here on stackoverflow telling me to use cout << std::fixed, but this function will return float values with decimal point which is not accepted on Codeforces. After a little bit of google search I found this following formula to calculate floor value of `a/b`.

`floor = (a/b) + ((a%b)!=0)`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The formula makes sense, but what if `a, b` were non-integers (in my case: `log(x)/log(y)`)? Does it still work?

Comment: @AvidSeeker No, it doesn't work for non-integers because you can't perform binary operator `%` on them. I think I did not answer your actual question. I'll help you sure if I find the answer.